# How to put inline function in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to write a C++ program that prompts the user for the radius of a circle then calls inline function `circleArea()` to calculate the area of that circle

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class Circle {
  private:
    float radius;

  public:
    inline void circleArea(float)

    void input() {
      cout<<"\nEnter the radius of circle";
      cin>>radius;
    }

    Circle() {
      float radius=0.0;
    }
};

void circleArea()
{
  float a,r;
  a=(3.14*r*r);
}

int main()
{
  Circle c;
  c.input();
  c.circleArea();
}
```

Here i don't understand how to put inline function, and i am not getting any output, my output shows blank space after putting the value of radius.

Comment: Try in `main` to use `cout << c.circleArea() << endl` or something similar. The code is generally problematic. You might want to read some C++ or design book.

Comment: Compile time error is what you should be getting...

Comment: I have no idea why there is a class in this code *at all*.

Comment: You need to get functions working at all before worrying about *inline*. Get a good book and work methodically through that, a couple of hours every day: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 0):

`void circleArea` should be `void Circle::circleArea`. As written it's not a member function. Once that's done, note that `a` is a local variable in the function; when the function returns, the value of `a` is gone.

To make `circleArea` inline, mark it inline at the point where it's **defined**. But that's an issue for the future.